# How to transform adjacent XML lists using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I've been using XSLT to clean up some legacy XML code into a cleaner format. Here's a case I haven't figured out a proper solution to. The starting XML looks like this:

```
<MyPoints>
  <X_Values>
    <X>11</X>
    <X>12</X>
    <X>13</X>
  </X_Values>
  <Y_Values>
    <Y>21</Y>
    <Y>22</Y>
    <Y>23</Y>
  </Y_Values>
</MyPoints>
```

Here's what I would like to get:

```
<MyPoints>
  <Values>
    <Value X="11" Y="21" />
    <Value X="12" Y="22" />
    <Value X="13" Y="23" />
  </Values>
</MyPoints>
```

X_Values and Y_Values are guaranteed to have the same number of elements. I want to do this for 3D points as well, but that should be a trivial extension of the solution.

XSLT 1.0 would be nice if possible.

Comment: Regarding your Edit: My previous answer was rubbish, see my update.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I realized on my way home that the second use of position() didn't make any sense to me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `position()` should do the trick. The relevant part:

```
<xsl:for-each select="/MyPoints/X_Values/X">
  <xsl:variable name="i"><xsl:value-of select="position()" /></xsl:variable>
  <Value X="{.}" Y="{/MyPoints/Y_Values/Y[position()=$i]}" />
</xsl:for-each>
```

A full stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
  version="1.0"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
>
  <xsl:output
    method="xml"
    version="1.0"
    indent="yes"
    doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN"
    doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd"
  />

<xsl:template match="/">
<MyPoints><Values>
<xsl:for-each select="/MyPoints/X_Values/X">
  <xsl:variable name="i"><xsl:value-of select="position()" /></xsl:variable>
  <Value X="{.}" Y="{/MyPoints/Y_Values/Y[position()=$i]}" />
</xsl:for-each>
</Values></MyPoints>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! I wasn't able to find clear documentation on how position() actually works, this makes a lot more sense now. I'll give it a try right now.

Comment: Updated solution works perfectly. I should note that to get a proper relative XPath, you have to go back two levels, as in `Y={../../Y_values/Y[position()=$i]"`